# PHP How to access this array GLOBALLY?

Tags: php, arrays, global-variables

I'm not so advanced with PHP and am looking for the best solution to the following:

- I have a PHP array that holds important information about my script that

I need to RE-USE this frequently in my script.

```
$my_settings = array('width'=>'300', 'height'=>'200', ...);
```

- I store that in a MySQL db.
- The PHP script needs to get that array from MySQL once each time it runs in order to know how to compose the view.

(The array will eventually become quite large... Maybe few hundred rows...)

What is the best practice to get and define this array only ONCE in the beginning of my script, so I can re-use it all the time by other functions etc...?

Is it by defining it globally?

```
global $my_settings;
$my_settings = get_my_settings_from_db();

function returnSetting($key='') {
 global $my_settings;
 return $my_settings[$key];

}
```

Or is this bad idea?

What is the most efficient way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Never ever use the `global` keyword. If you are going to need it often I would look into caching.

Comment: that's pretty much how it's done ... except you don't need the first global $my_settings;. you only need that within functions that will use it.

Comment: You also don't need the second `global` or any `global` for that matter.

Comment: How come you want to do this by using globals instead of passing the array to the function as an argument? I see no huge difference between using `function returnSettings($key, $my_settings)` and `function returnSetting($key='') {global $my_settings;...`, you still have to type and by using globals you are adding a variable to global namespace which forces you to remember that you've done it, and hope you didn't overwrite something already living in the global namespace. Basically, it's a bad idea.

Comment: @Jamie - this reminds me of killing a mosquito with a rifle. Why use the rifle for such a trivial task - it's beyond me :)

Comment: what is OOP and how it is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `global` (which is a bad thing to do) you should inject the variable (or even better the part you need into the function that needs it):

```
$my_settings = get_my_settings_from_db();

function returnSetting($settings, $key='') {
     return $settings[$key];
}

returnSetting($my_settings, $key);
```

Or perhaps better create a settings class:

```
class Settings
{
    protected $settings;

    public function __construct($settings)
    {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

    public function getSetting($key)
    {
        return $this->settings[$key];
    }
}

// you only create one instance per request, so you would do this in for example your bootstrap file
$settings = new Settings($my_settings);
```

Let's say you have a class which needs some settings you could do the following:

```
class Foo
{
    protected $settings;

    public function __construct($settings)
    {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    {

    public function bar()
    {
        // do something which requires a setting
        echo $this->settings->getSetting('dimensions');
    }
}

$settings = new Settings($my_settings);
$foo = new Foo($settings);
$foo->bar();
```

When doing it this you will make you code better testable and maintainable.

Note this is just something I written with a beer in one hand and it is untested, but you should get the idea. :-)

Comment: How you can access it in standalone function without global or refer object as parameter?

Comment: By [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) into the classes / function that need it.

Comment: The topic was to access an array throw the application, if we want to suggest a complete way to create a Settings class, I do not think that instantiate a class is a good idea, and also need to add more validations. As you said, this class do the same as global or static I do not see any added value, and setup is no the right way for a Settings class. :P

Comment: @DanielAranda *sigh* this class doesn't do the same as `global`. I told you that *your* definition basically had the same problems as when using the `global` keyword. I.e. global state and tight coupling.

Comment: I'm not talking about scope! sigh! I'm talking about the added value on both codes, both do the same, the problem is that your class is only accessible where it is declared, in other areas that does not have access to the instance that you created, how they get the value? they will not have access, so you method fail. This is the reason because if we do not want to use static var(the easiest way) we must apply patterns like Singleton, instead of what you are suggesting. :P

Comment: HOW does one reference `$settings` from a function, other than by calling `global $settings` in the function?

Comment: @DanielAranda , please ,stop embarrassing yourself.

Comment: @neokio Did you even open the link about dependency injection? Or [don't take my word](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/11/11/clean-code-talks-dependency-injection/).

Comment: Maybe his code is purely procedural (for personal use) and he doesn't want to rewrite everything from scratch to make it OOP. Although he did ask our opinion.

Comment: @PeeHaa Yes, but it was written by robots, and for Java (not PHP), and therefore difficult for me to comprehend. Thanks for the new link tho, I'll check that out...

Comment: @Tivie Even with procedural code you can use dependency injection. You will simply inject it into the function. The same benefits (mostly apply).

Comment: @tereško I'm using only arguments. I know what I'm talking, if you do not catch it is other topic. But I'm using arguments. If you think that dependency injection works better for a global values, it is respectable but my thought is that is no the better way. I cannot figure passing a settings instance to my overall 200 views that needs the settings. If you like this way, I respect I do not see that you are embarrassing yourself, is just other way to work.

Comment: @neokio there is a entire series of that which was really an eye-opener when I first saw it. If you are serious and you want to learn you should [read this](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/) and [watch these](http://www.g-truc.net/post-0182.html). I don't think Daniel is interested, but it also would benefit him.

Comment: For completeness some links: [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)), [GRASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)), [STUPID](http://nikic.github.com/2011/12/27/Dont-be-STUPID-GRASP-SOLID.html).

Comment: @PeeHaa Thank You! I'm not close to read new stuff or change my opinion. With your latest articles I got it that Singleton is consider a Warning Signs. It is interested I have other thoughts but to not loop it, may be I will create other topic to discuss about best practices creating Settings classes.

Comment: @DanielAranda Feel free to come to [PHP chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) and talk about it.

Comment: PeeHaa Yes, of course he can. But maybe the OP is building it's script on top of another script. Drupal 6, for instance, uses hooks (poor man Observer pattern) to call determined module functions and you can't change function definitions(add extra arguments). He asked how to access a var globally... I think that's what @Daniel Aranda was trying to say.

Comment: @PeeHaa Those links are awesome. Very advanced concepts. I've been learning PHP OOP by looking at other peoples code. So it seems I have some bad habits to unlearn.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the first global like this:

```
$my_settings = get_my_settings_from_db();

function returnSetting($key='') {
 global $my_settings;
 return $my_settings[$key];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Global is nice! <- it is what I will say if Today was July, 2002

But in the 2012 global must be killed by all of the Ninja devs.

Try to use a static var for this:

```
class DataCollector{
    static $my_settings = array('width'=>'300', 'height'=>'200');
}

//You could use the values at ANY place or function
echo DataCollector::$my_settings['width'];
```

Also read about OOP basics.

Comment: +1 for showing a reasonable alternative, and not just being snarky

Comment: Settings from databse. How you set them as static property?

Comment: `static` is the same as a `global` in this example.

Comment: DataCollector::$my_settings['width'] = '500'; static does NOT mean const, 98% confuse it. You could edit static vars at runtime! but you cannot do it on const. So there is not any problem updating the static value with a DB return.

Comment: Thanks, but how about the fact that I need to get the settings from MySQL db? Will calling the object each time not also call the MySQL db each time to get the array? Like this: $my_settings = get_my_settings_from_db();

Comment: @PeeHaa is not the same, one is a old school concept and have issues to implement around applications, static is a good implementation of OOP, I do not feel that is the same. Not sure your thoughts to say that it is the same. :P

Comment: It has the same problems. How are you going to unit test that?

Comment: `static` variables are not part of object oriented paradigm

Comment: @user1033406 just store one time as you did with the global var: DataCollector::$my_settings = db_result(); later in the application you could use the values: DataCollector::$my_settings['width']; as you tried with globals. The behavior is the same, we are just not using the heavy old global concept and we are using OOP, but there are not any limitation.

Comment: @DanielAranda: Apart from the `$`-sign in front of the label, how can one not see that `$global` and `global_class_name::$global` is actually the same type of variable? Look what you write. And look what you need to know to access that variable: it's global label. And how do both actually differ apart from the slight difference in syntax? Not at all. Both are globally accessible variables in PHP.

Comment: @hakre the question is "PHP How to access this array GLOBALLY?" I answered that, with a better syntax for this times. Also regarding of best practices to build a Settings class we could create another topic, that is my point.

Comment: @DanielAranda Not really - you answered by first bashing globals, then you used a global variable in your answer... That's not a "better syntax for the times," it's just a lazy approach to the situation and not even OOP.

Comment: @orourkek I think that it is just a better syntax. I was not intending to talk about patterns or other paradigms. Both are globals, I agree, what I mean when said that globals is from old school I mean the keyword.

Comment: The less intrusive and more clear a syntax is, the better. From that standpoint, just using a global variable is OK. However the way you coin your answer makes no sense. First you tell global variable's aren't the mode of current times (which is not a reason at all), and then only to tell that a slightly differently looking global variable "chest la mode". So you obviously are not giving any arguments but you're discussing styling questions for no obvious reasons. That can never be a better syntax.  And this has nothing to do with patterns or paradigms. But who to convince?

Answer (score -1):

#### use $GLOBALS['my_settings']

$GLOBAL is a php super global variable which can be used instead of 'global' keyword to access variables from global scope, i.e. the variables which can be accessed from anywhere in a php script even within functions or methods.

```
$my_settings = array('width'=>'300', 'height'=>'200', ...);
function blablabla() {
  $b = $GLOBALS['my_settings'] ;
  echo $b ;
}
```

Comment: $GLOBAL is a php super global variable which can be used instead of 'global' keyword to access variables from global scope, i.e. the variables which can be accessed from anywhere in a php script even within functions or methods.

Answer (score -2):

```
function getSettings($id, $type) {
if(!$id == 0) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'database' WHERE 'id' = '".$id."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
if($type == "setting1") {
        return $row['setting1'];
    } elseif($type == "setting2") {
        return $row['setting2'];
    } elseif($type == "setting3") {
        return $row['setting3'];
    } elseif($type == "setting4") {
        return $row['setting4'];
    } else {
        return "Wrong Input";
        }
} } else { return "Not Initialized";}
else { return "No $id input"; }}}
```

Store login in `$_SESSION` and call with `getSetting($_SESSION['id'], "setting1")`

Comment: this option gives me the runs

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).