# Declaring Global Array in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to declare a global array and put data in it with a function.

It works only if the global variable is a string but not if it's an array:

```
$data = iterate("USER361");
print_r($data);

function iterate($username) 
{
    global $gv_array;

    $sql = "select * from account where sponsor = '$username'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            $this_user = $row['username'];
            $this_name = $row['full_name'];
            $this_tier = $row['tier'];

            $my_array = array("username"=>$this_user,"name"=>$this_name,"tier"=>$this_tier);
            array_push($gv_array[],$my_array);

            iterate($row['username']);
        }

}//end of iterate
```

The error I get is:

> PHP Warning:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /var/www/html/inc/code.php on line 29

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP How to access this array GLOBALLY?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743275/php-how-to-access-this-array-globally)

Comment: shouldn't this line `array_push($gv_array[],$my_array);` be `array_push($gv_array,$my_array);`

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876222/declaring-a-global-array

Comment: Flagging as `a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error` since the solution has nothing to do with globality of variables and using them inside functions. This also applies: `This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `$gv_array` it's an array then the problem is here `array_push($gv_array[],$my_array);` remove the square brackets.

```
array_push($gv_array,$my_array);
```